# What are the internals of merge followed by aggregation with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

One very common use case for data.table in my work is to merge two tables followed by aggregation where the intermediary result not needed further on.

Example:

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(200)
a.DT <- data.table(k1=2000+sample.int(12, 50, replace = TRUE))[
  , k2 := month.abb[(sample(12, .N, replace = TRUE))]][
    , .(val = rnbinom(1, 50, .8))
    , by = .(k1, k2)]

b.DT <- a.DT[ 
  , .(k3 = LETTERS[7:12]), by = k1][
    , adj1 := 1/rbeta(1, 2, 5)
    , by= k3][
    , adj2 := rbeta(.N, 5, .5)]

setkey(a.DT, k1)
setkey(b.DT, k1)

result.DT <- a.DT[b.DT, allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  , .(weighted = sum(val * adj1 * adj2))
  , by = .(k3, k1, k2)]
```

My question is if the intermediary data.table "a.DT[b.DT, allow.cartesian = TRUE]" is first allocated in full or is it directly piped into the following aggregation?

Yours,
Alexander

Comment: Yes, the intermediate table is created first, and I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "directly piped".

Comment: By "directly piped" I mean that the intermediate table is never built fully, but as soon as the first row of b.DT is merged with a.DT, the rows may be fed into the following aggregation and discarded instead of keeping them in memory.

My feeling is that this might be happening since I have not found it to occupy the kind of memory that would imply that the intermediate table is there.

Comment: The entire merge result is computed first and only when that's finished is the second set of brackets evaluated.

Comment: @eddi you should post it as answer. @OP each `[` in data.table chain materialize the data, `data.table` optimization is performed within the single `[...]`.